# Entity form in ctools modal

Tags: 7

I'm trying to add an entity form in Ctools popup. I'm using this module https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/andreymaximov/2058521 . My entity form path is like this eform/submit/quote

module docs say use this as link

modal_forms/%ctools_js/eform/submit/%entityform_empty

I'm really lost how to put my quote entity form here according to that link.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying to use [Ctools Automodal](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal) module. It's really easy to use just look at the project page:

> Provides automatic modal support for any hook_menu() paths that have
>   'modal' => TRUE defined. This makes it easy to add optional modal
>   support in any contrib module and helps reduce the burden on module
>   developers to support modals.
>
> Example Usage

```
<?php
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['mymodule/form'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('mymodule_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer mymodule'),
    'modal' => TRUE, // This line is where the magic happens.
  );
}
?>
```